# Username that doesn't exist showing up in errors

Tags: macos, terminal, nvm

When trying to update my Node version on my Mac, I get confusing an strange errors, and they contain the path `/Users/previous-computer-username`, where I have, obviously, "redacted" the actual path section that is a username that doesn't exist on this computer!

```
➜  current-folder git:(master) ✗ nvm install v16.8.1
mkdir: /Users/previous-computer-username: Permission denied
mkdir: /Users/previous-computer-username: Permission denied
Version 'v16.8.1' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
```

(I'm also confused why nvm can't find `v16.8.1`, or `16.8.1`, which are definitely real versions and come up in `nvm ls-remote`; or why any `mkdir` is happening, or why the error is "Permission denied" rather than "Doesn't exist")

`ls /Users` does not include `previous-computer-username`

What on earth might be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Some config is referencing that path.
There is not enough information to find out where, but try to find it using `grep -iRI previous-computer-username ~` and if that's not helpful also `grep -iRI previous-computer-username /etc/`

This will tell you where the name is referenced, and you need to fix this config.

You probably copied some old config from somewhere, and that's the issue.